# Troubles with my vertical alignment

Tags: html, css

I've followed several tutorials or "tips" on how to accomplish this, yet it seems when I do one thing, it breaks something else which is just pushing me further away from my goal.

Currently its center aligned as I want, now to center align it vertically.

'line-height' ends up messing with my borders which isn't helping either. I could of sworn I have dealt with this in the past, but I can't find any old sources of mine that had this solved.

Code:

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 76px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
#space {
  width: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.child {
  width: 75px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #8CAAD2;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="child">Call Us</span>
  <div id="space"></div>
  <span class="child">Call Us</span>
</div>
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hbebtkxd/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flexbox` with `align-items:center;` and `justify-content:center` on `.parent`.

```css
.parent{
  width:100%;
  height:76px;
  border:1px solid black;
  border-radius:15px;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:flexbox;
  display:flex;
  text-align:center;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
#space{
  width:5px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.child{
  width:75px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  border:1px solid #8CAAD2;
  border-radius:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<span class="child">Call Us</span>
<div id="space"></div>
<span class="child">Call Us</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps add a note about flex box  browser (un)support.

Comment: This seems to be the only one that properly works on my site. All the others break in some way.

Comment: @Travis make sure to double check older versions of IE - if that is important for you.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to `space` and you will have it vertically aligned:

```
height: 100%;
vertical-align: middle;
```

updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mepr5uwm/)

snippet below:

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 76px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
#space {
  width: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.child {
  width: 75px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #8CAAD2;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="child">Call Us</span>
  <div id="space"></div>
  <span class="child">Call Us</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @Travis: let me know you thoughts on this... Thanks!

Comment: This works because 100% height is given. Not sure it's the clean way, but it works. :)

Comment: @AllDani one of the usual ways to vertically align `inline-block` elements... normally I'd use a pseudo element...

Comment: Ok. Is inline-block the suggested value when vertical alignment is desired?

Comment: nope, when using `inline-block` elements you can do it like this... there is way to vertical align using `line-height` too when using `inline-block`

Comment: I'm a bit confused. If inline-block is not the suggested way, why use it with line-height? Or do you mean that line-height should be used instead of inline-block?

Comment: `inline-block` is a `display` type and each `display` has its use cases... there are standard ways of vertical alignment for each `display`... that's what I meant :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <span class="link">Call Us</span>
    <span class="link">Call Us</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent{
  width:100%;
  height:76px;
  border:1px solid black;
  border-radius:15px;
  display:table;
  text-align:center;
}
.child {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.link {
  width:75px;
  border:1px solid #8CAAD2;
  border-radius:10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.link:first-child {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hbebtkxd/2/